Additional services not starting in `docker compose`
docker-compose.yaml
services:
  mailserver:
    image: ghcr.io/docker-mailserver/docker-mailserver:latest
    container_name: mailserver
    hostname: dms.example.com
    ports:
      - "25:25"
      - "1465:465"
      - "1587:587"
      - "1993:993"
      - "4190:4190"
    volumes:
      - /docker/data/docker-mailserver/scripts/:/scripts/
    restart: always

Beginning of my getmail service
...
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          getmail
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network $named $time $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $network $named $time $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Description:       download mail
### END INIT INFO
...

I use the above docker-compose.yaml to run docker-mailserver. However, I need it to run another 4 getmail which runs /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver, so this must take place inside the container.
The debian image creates service scripts in /etc/init.d. I have created my own getmail and was able to control the service correctly using service getmail start/stop/restart.
The issue is, I cannot get it to run when the container starts even though I already ran update-rc.d getmail defaults. Any ideas?
